# Method to increment array parameter without types

Tags: arrays, vb.net, generics

I'm trying to create a method to perform both increment and value assignment operations, something like this:

```
Public Sub ArrayAdd(ByRef arr As Object(), newItem As Object)
        Try
            If IsNothing(arr) Then
                arr = New Object() {newItem}
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Array.Resize(arr, arr.Length + 1)
            arr(arr.Length - 1) = newItem
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New ApplicationException(ex.Message, ex)
        End Try
    End Sub`
```

Using this method generates type conversion errors, so I would like to use generics `Of T` (without success).

Comment: You didn't mention what Type your `List<T>` and `newItem` will be or whether `T` is meant to be an Interface. You should probably post your failed attempt to create a generic method. Also, is there a specific reason to use an Array instead of a List or similar collection (so you don't need to handle this operation *manually*)?

Comment: Found a solution, I'll write it as answer at this post. The reason behind this is because array are faster in read/write/iteration operations, and I'm (Alas) developing a winform application. I'll need to optimize as much as possible.

Comment: List<T> uses an array behind the scene and implements tested and optimized code to cache, size and resize the content. What you're trying to do has no real use. It's not the only existing collection Type. You have other collection types that can perform better, to choose based on the concrete use case. The WinForms platform has no direct connection to this either. You should post a specific question in relation to what you're actually trying to do with your array(s).

Comment: If you need to optimize, then presumably you've already measured performance with both `Array` and `List(Of T)` under your typical workload and found that `Array` is significantly faster?  It's always dangerous to assume what the choke points will be in your code without measuring.

Comment: Yes, same programs developed with arrays are quite faster then with lists. Anyway, the last improvement that I would achieve is changing, where possible, from AoS to Soa. I found out this difference between Lists and Arrays during a course by Dmitri Nesteruk, in a lecture about Composite Proxies, where he used arrays instead of lists, and I simply wondered why.

Comment: After deeper tests, I saw that arrays are faster for some operations, but a lot slower for others. Making an avarage, I'd say that Lists are faster, better if looped through a standard "For" than a "For Each"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic method works exactly as you'd expect:

```vb
Public Sub AppendElement(Of T)(ByRef array As T(), element As T)
    If array Is Nothing Then
        array = {element}
    Else
        Dim upperBound = array.Length

        System.Array.Resize(array, upperBound + 1)
        array(upperBound) = element
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, I just came to the same solution, for some strange reason Visual Studio didn't let me write it down just like that, I had to refactor it with the "Change Signature" command. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method implementation

```
   Public Sub ArrayAdd(Of T)(ByRef arr() As T, item As T)
    Try
        If IsNothing(arr) Then
            arr = New T() {item}
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Array.Resize(arr, arr.Length + 1)
        arr(arr.Length - 1) = item
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New ApplicationException(ex.Message, ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```